# Django: Check if object is last linked one to another

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a delete function in django (python).
I need to delete a Site. A Site can be linked to multiple Groups.
Before the Site can be deleted, I have to check if the Site is the last Site from a Group.
I'm thinking of how to do this the most efficiently.
Should I query for all the Sites for all the groups to which the site is linked, before I delete the site and check if the site is the only linked one?

```
    site = get_object_or_404(Site, pk=site_pk)
    group = Group.objects.prefetch_related("user_site").filter(
        user_site__site_id=site_pk
    )

    site.delete()
```

Site model:
- no relations, just basic attributes

Group model:

has a name and

```
def get_linked_sites(self):
    user_sites = self.usersites.all()
    return [usersite.usersite.site.id for usersite in user_sites]
```

UserSite model:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sites")
site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="users")
group = models.ForeignKey(
    Group,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name="user_site",
    default=None,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
```

UserSiteGroup model:

```
 usersite = models.ForeignKey(
        UserSite, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="groups"
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usersites")
```

Solution (but can maybe be better?):

```
    site = get_object_or_404(Site, pk=site_pk)

    groups = (
        Group.objects.filter(usersites__usersite__site_id=site_pk)
        .prefetch_related("usersites__usersite")
        .distinct()
        .all()
    )

    for group in groups:
        if len(group.get_linked_sites()) > 1:
            group.delete()

    site.delete()
```

Comment: Can you show your site model?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your definition of Group has a Site foreign key? If so, you can add or use a related name there, e.g.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    ...
    site = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="groups")
```

Then you can simply check with

```
if not user_site.groups.all().exists():
    user_site.delete()
```

Comment: I added the models, could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
group = Group.objects.get(pk=site.group_id)
if group.site_set.exclude(pk=site.id).count == 0:
    site.delete()
    group.delete()
```

Comment: So A group can have multiple site's linked to it. I need to check if the site is the last one in the group. If it is, delete the group to. This does not delete the group though?

Comment: Does this work if the site is linked to multiple groups? Shouldn't there be a .all(). I have a working solution, but I guess it can be better. I post it in the original question

Comment: This codes, find group of site and after, find sites related to this founded group. Your Site model related to Group model with ForeignKey, so one site can have only one group. Am i right?

Comment: No, sorry if I was not clear. One site can be linked to multiple groups

Comment: is it with UserSiteGroup table? I focused only UserSite table, I missed UserSiteGroup.